# Python: Assigning staticmethod to class variable gives error

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method

I want to assign a static method to a class variable in Python, and below is what my code looks like.

```
class Klass:
    classVariable = None

    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print "method called"        

Klass.classVariable = Klass.method        
Klass.method()
Klass.classVariable()
```

This gave me an error at the last line,
`TypeError: unbound method method() must be called with Klass instance as first argument (got nothing instead).`

But when I change the static method to class method it works. Can anyone give me any idea of why this is the case?

Comment: Interesting question.  Not surprisingly, It works in python3.x (if you fix the print statement)...

Comment: Probably a bug with decorators in python2

Comment: @Natecat -- I don't think this is a bug, and definitely not a bug with _decorators_.  I suppose one could argue that it's a bug with `staticmethod` in general ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Backstory (descriptor protocol)

First, we need to know a little about python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html)...

For this answer, it should be enough to know the following:

1. **Functions are descriptors.**
2. Binding behavior of methods (i.e. how a method knows what `self` to pass) is implemented via the function's `__get__` method and the built-in descriptor protocol.
3. **When you put a descriptor `foo` on a class, accessing the descriptor actually calls the `.__get__` method.**  (This is really just a generalization of statement 2)

In other words:

```
class Foo(object):
    val = some_descriptor
```

When I do:

```
result = Foo.val
```

Python actually does:

```
Foo.val.__get__(None, Foo)
```

When I do:

```
f = Foo()
f.val
```

python does:

```
f = Foo()
type(f).val.__get__(f, type(f))
```

#### Now the good stuff.

It looks like (on python2.x), `staticmethod` is implemented such that its `__get__` method returns a regular function.  You can see this by printing the type of `Klass.method`:

```
print type(Klass.method)  # <type 'function'>
```

So what we've learned is that the method returned by `Klass.method.__get__` is just a regular function.

When you put that regular function onto a class, its `__get__` method returns an `instancemethod` (which expects a `self` argument).  This isn't surprising ... We do it all the time:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print self
```

Is no different to python than:

```
def bar(self):
    print self

class Foo(object):
    pass

Foo.bar = bar
```

except that the first version is a lot easier to read and doesn't clutter your module namespace.

So now we've explained how your staticmethod turned into an instance method.  Is there anything we can do about it?

#### Solution

When you put the method onto the class, designate it as a `staticmethod` again and it will work out Ok.

```
class Klass(object):  # inheriting from object is a good idea.
    classVariable = None

    @staticmethod
    def method():
        print("method called")

Klass.classVariable = staticmethod(Klass.method)  # Note extra staticmethod
Klass.method()
Klass.classVariable()
```

#### Appendix -- Re-implementation of `@staticmethod`

If you're a little but curious how you might implement `staticmethod` to *not* have this problem -- Here's an example:

```
class StaticMethod(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn

    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        return self

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)


class Klass(object):
    classVariable = None

    @StaticMethod
    def method():
        print("method called")

Klass.classVariable = Klass.method
Klass.method()
Klass.classVariable()
Klass().method()
Klass().classVariable()
```

The trick here is that my `__get__` doesn't return a function.  It returns *itself*.  When you put it on a different class (or the same class), its `__get__` will still just return itself.  Since it is returning itself from `__get__`, it needs to pretend to be a function (so it can be called after "__gotten__") so I implement a custom `__call__` method to do the right thing (pass through to the delegate function and return the result).

<sup>Please note, *I'm not advocating that you use this `StaticMethod` instead of `staticmethod`*.  It'll be less efficient and not as introspectible (and probably confusing for your code readers).  This is only for educational purposes.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer :)