# Assign static methods to a class

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

I am using `Object.assign` to assign functions to classes, however, am unsure of how to assign static methods to it.

For example, assuming I have `class A` and `class B` and I want to assign some methods to them:

```
var myfunctions = {
  method: function() {
  }
};
Object.assign(A, myfunctions);
Object.assign(B, myfunctions);
```

Could I do the same for static methods? (Eg. Assign the static method `function` to the class `A`, so I can call `A.function();`)

Comment: can you refer the link which is clear https://stackoverflow.com/a/37199949/8574868

Comment: Have you tried something like `A.prototype.myfunction = function () { ... //your code here }` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to the prototype of the class, like that:

```
Object.assign(A.prototype, functionsObject);
```