# Difference between using the decorator and the function with staticmethod

Tags: python, static-methods

I am trying to create a class which gets given a function, which will then be run from that instance. However, when I tried to use `staticmethod`, I discovered that there is a difference between using the decorator and just passing `staticmethod` a function.

```
class WithDec():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def stat(val):
        return val + 1


def OuterStat(val):
    return val + 1

class WithoutDec():
    def __init__(self, stat):
        self.stat = staticmethod(stat)
```

With these two classes, the following occurs.

```
>>> WithDec().stat(2)
3
>>> WithoutDec(OuterStat).stat(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

What is going on, and what can I do to stop it.

Comment: This makes no sense - how could a static method be an instance attribute, and why are you trying to make it one? If you want it to belong to the instance and be callable from the instance, just write `self.stat = stat`.

Comment: You presented working code in the first example. So, what are you asking for?

Comment: If any of the answers below helped you solve your problem, please consider upvoting and/or accepting, as appropriate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Static methods still work through the descriptor protocol, meaning that when it is a *class* attribute, accessing it via an instance still means that the `__get__` method will be called to return an object that actually gets called. That is,

```
WithDec().stat(2)
```

is equivalent to

```
w = WithDec()
w.stat(2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
WithDec.stat.__get__(w, WithDec)(2)
```

However, the descriptor protocol is *not* invoked when the static method is an *instance* attribute, as is the case with `WithoutDec`. In that case

```
WithoutDec().stat(2)
```

tries to call the literal `staticmethod` instance `stat`, not the the function returned by `stat.__get__`.

What you wanted was to use `staticmethod` to create a class attribute, just not via decorator syntax:

```
class WithoutDec():

    def stat(val):
        return val + 1

    stat = staticmethod(stat)
```

You first bind `stat` to a regular function (it's not really an instance method until you try to *use* it as an instance method), then *replace* the function with a `staticmethod` instance wrapping the original function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very inspiring solution on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199842/python-assigning-staticmethod-to-class-variable-gives-error). Indeed your code is not very pythonic, and attributes a static method to an attribute of an instance of your class. The following code works:

```py
class WithoutDec():
    
    stat = None

    @staticmethod
    def OuterStat(val):
        return val + 1
```

then you call:

```
my_without_dec = WithoutDec()
my_without_dec.stat = WithotuDec.OuterStat
my_without_dec.stat(2)
```

later if you want to create a new method, you call:

```
def new_func(val):
    return val+1

WithoutDec.newStat = staticmethod(new_func)
my_without_dec.stat = WithoutDec.newStat
my_without_dec.stat(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to use `staticmethod()` inside `__init__`, which is used to create an instance of the class, instead of at the class level directly, which defines the class, its methods and its static methods.

This code works:

```py
def OuterStat(val):
    return val + 1

class WithoutDec():
    stat = staticmethod(OuterStat)
```

```py
>>> WithoutDec.stat(2)
3
```

Note that trying to create an instance of `WithoutDec` with its own, different, version of stat, is contrary to the meaning of a method being static.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -
In this case, you just have to add the function as an attribute of the instance, it will work as expected, no need for any decorators:

```py
def OuterStat(val):
    return val + 1

class WithoutDec():
    def __init__(self, stat):
        self.stat = stat
```

The thing is: there is a difference if a function is an attribute of *the class* or an attribute of the *instance*. When it is set inside an instance method with `self.func = X`, it becomes an instance attribute - Python retrieves it the way it was stored, with no modifications, and it is simply another reference to the original function that can be called.

When a function is stored as a *class*  attibute, instead, the default behavior is that it is used as an instance method: upon retrieving the function from an instance, Python arranges things so that  `self` will be injected as the first argument to that function. In this case, the decorators `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` exist to modify this behavior (injetct the class for `classmethod` or make no injection for `staticmethod`).

The thing is that `staticmethod` does not return a function - it returns a descriptor to be used as a class attribute, so that when the decorated function is retrieved from a class, it works as a plain function.

(Internal detail: all 3 behaviors: instance method, classmethod and staticmethod are implementing by having an appropriate `__get__` method on the object that is used as an attribute to the class).

**NB**: There were some discussions in making "staticmethod" to become itself "callable", and simply call the wrapped function - I just checked it made it into Pythonn 3.10 beta 1. This means that your example code will work as is for Python 3.10  - nonetheless, the staticmethod call there is redundant, as stated in the beggining of this answer, and should not be used.